# Using CSS Selector for selenium. Filtering fields when fields which are really similar. See Scenario

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

The following CSS is returning these 2 fields using firefinder.

```
tr[class="ui-widget-content footrow footrow-ltr"] td[aria-describedby*="Active_Customers"]
```

Returns:

```
<td aria-describedby="Grid_1201748220_Active_Customers" style="width: 150px;" role="gridcell">

<td aria-describedby="Grid_1201748220_New_Active_Customers" style="width: 150px;" role="gridcell">
```

As one can see the difference between them is just (*New*) (the first result). Is there a way, just by using CSS locators to get Active_Customers ONLY(not with the New) (the first result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any other way than to exclude the one with "New" in it (unfortunately resulting in an even longer selector):

```
tr[class="ui-widget-content footrow footrow-ltr"] td[aria-describedby*="Active_Customers"]:not([aria-describedby*="New_Active_Customers"])
```

Comment: I thought I've tried this... but this is exactly what I needed.